# Preventing overfitting in transfer learning using TensorFlow and Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning, tensorflow-hub

I've got a TensorFlow 2 model with a pre-trained Keras layer coming from TensorFlow Hub. I want to fine-tune the weights in this sub-model to suit my dataset, but if I do that naively by setting `trainable=True` and `training=True`, my model will grossly overfit.

If I had the actual layers of the underlying model under my control, I would insert dropout layers or set L2 coefficient on those individual layers. But the layers are imported to my network using TensorFlow Hub [`KerasLayer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/api_docs/python/hub/KerasLayer) method. Also, I suspect that the underlying model is quite complicated.

I wonder what's the standard practice for solving this kind of issues.

Maybe there is a way to force regularization to the whole network somehow? I know that in TensorFlow 1, there were optimizers like [`ProximalAdagradOptimizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/ProximalAdagradOptimizer) that took L2 coefficients. In TensorFlow 2, the only optimizer like this is [FTRL](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/optimizers/Ftrl), but it's hard for me to make it work for my dataset.

Answer (score 4):

I "solved" it by

- pretraining non-transferred parts of the model,
- then turning on learning for the shared layers,
- introducing early stopping,
- and configuring the optimizer to go really slow.

This way, I managed to not damage the transferred layers too much. Anyway, I still wonder whether this is the best one can do.